# Появляющиеся поле на JQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Друзья, приветствую.

Пишу небольшой функционал для посетителей - форму подписки, все получилось довольно симпатично, но столкнулся с проблемой, когда появляется блок после нажатия на кнопку, то он почему-то при наведении ведет себя как кнопка по которой нажали.

Подскажите решение...

Пример здесь http://jsfiddle.net/TZ2at/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

структура там страшненькая, но с пивом покатит. вот чуток подровнял. http://jsfiddle.net/TZ2at/2/

На самом деле там много чего нужно переделать

Comment: спасибо. да понятное дело, просто это пока не совершенство, надо как говориться ошкурить и снять фасочку,

Comment: почему вообще блок наследует некоторые свойства от кнопки? как это отключить?